# Fatal Error Required Validator DateTime Field not working

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-api

I created a new required Field Validator for a DateTime field. Image Attached. I added the Fatal Error message so the user cannot save.

[image]

I added the validation Rule to the template field. Images Attached

[image]

[image]

[image]

The user edits the page for the very first time, it shows the Red Mark on side of the field. It shows in all the three places. `Quick Action Bar, Validation Button and Validation Bar`.
Image Attached.

[image]

The user when tries to save the Sitecore error messages comes up. That what it should do. The user enters the date and saves and the page is saved.

The problem I am facing is, when the user edits the page again and clears the date, and then tries to save, the error message comes up, that what it should do, but the `quick action bar` and `validation bar` does not show that(red vertical line), it is required. I can only see, if I go to Review and click on Validation.
image attached.

[image]

I tested this on a single line text field and it works every time, but for Datetime field it is not working if you do the second time.

Comment: That seems like a Sitecore bug. Have you contacted with Sitecore Support?

Comment: Which version of Sitecore you are using?

Comment: I haven’t contacted the support yet. The ver of sitecore is 9.3 is there any other quick way of doing this.